# ThreadContextProvider service loader error in Quarkus During Integration tests

Tags: maven, quarkus

Im getting the following error in my quarkus app, but only in integration tests, when the tests are running as part of the maven build and not when running the tests within my IDE (or when running in dev mode).

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
            org.eclipse.microprofile.context.spi.ThreadContextProvider:
                io.quarkus.arc.runtime.context.ArcContextProvider not a subtype
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:589)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1236)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1383)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
        at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeContextManager$Builder.discoverThreadContextProviders(SmallRyeContextManager.java:293)
        at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeContextManager$Builder.build(SmallRyeContextManager.java:333)
        at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeContextManagerProvider.getContextManager(SmallRyeContextManagerProvider.java:48)
        at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeContextManagerProvider.getContextManager(SmallRyeContextManagerProvider.java:37)
        at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeContextManagerProvider.getManager(SmallRyeContextManagerProvider.java:97)
        at io.smallrye.context.SmallRyeThreadContext.getCurrentThreadContextOrDefaultContexts(SmallRyeThreadContext.java:160)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.context.DefaultContextPropagationInterceptor.getThreadContext(DefaultContextPropagationInterceptor.java:12)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.context.BaseContextPropagationInterceptor.decorate(BaseContextPropagationInterceptor.java:82)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.infrastructure.Infrastructure.decorate(Infrastructure.java:226)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnItem.transform(UniOnItem.java:115)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni.map(Uni.java:384)
        at ...
```

This looks like some classloading issue but having a debugger in the build shows that the loaded ThreadContextProvider is assignable from the loaded ArcContextProvider, Is there anything else I should be looking for here? A bit stumped.